# Creating exec file in c# project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi
How can I change a project from running in HTML file 
to run in exec file.
(I want to run a downloded project without using a browser)

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Use a different project template, like console application or windows form application. In case I totally misunderstand what you are trying to do. Provide some more info.

Comment: I downloded a silverlight project, and it is running only in the browser, and I want it to run in exec file

Comment: Maybe this can help up: http://hackingsilverlight.blogspot.com/2008/06/making-silverlight-run-as-exe.html